# What does the keyword loop in Java do?

Tags: java, loops

```
public class Test 
{
        public void add(int a) 
        {
            loop: for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                    for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++) 
                    {
                        if (a == 5) 
                        {
                        break loop;
                        }
                        System.out.println(i * j);
                    }
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] str)
        {
            Test t=new Test();
            t.add(4);s
        }
}
```

Comment: This is a label. Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: what are the down votes for?

Comment: There is no loop keyword.

Comment: @user3125280 I think they were for the former title and the lack of an explanatory paragraph. Anyway, this is a non-obvious question (I never actually used `break label` in my life) and I feel this one does not deserve downvotes at all.

Comment: @ZouZou i am enable to understand plz explain me

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo this code run

Comment: @user3184996 yeah, I know it does. Then? :) See my answer below

Comment: @user3184996 This is explained very well in the link I posted.

Comment: I'm not one of the down voters, but the moment I saw *"plz .. ???"* I was tempted to down-vote. It is best to spell words correctly and use only one question mark.  But for 'please' it is simpler to just leave it out entirely.  If people know the answer, they will give it.  Saying please is considered a waste of space, noise.

Comment: Even though I consider myself rather knowledgeable about the Java language, I didn't even know such a thing consisted. And I think it's an ok question, so I'll upvote it.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo that's my sentiment too, if it was just asked poorly (OP doesn't sound english native) then downvotes are unfair. it is really quite a good question, even if the explanation is simple/easy to find

Answer (score 1):

It's a shortcut for terminating both nested loops. Citing the [Branching Statements page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) from Java Tutorial:

> The break statement terminates the labeled statement; it does not transfer the flow of control to the label. Control flow is transferred to the statement immediately following the labeled (terminated) statement.

and

> An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, or do-while statement, but a labeled break terminates an outer statement.

It's not a keyword, it's a label you choose. Just mark the external loop with `labelName: ...`. Then, you can nest loops and exit from them all by calling `break labelName;`:

```
yourLabelName: for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; ++j) {
        break yourLabelName;
    }
}
// After calling break yourLabelName, you will end up here
```

In your case, when `a == 5`, then both loops are exited and the `add()` method terminates  (returns).

Answer (score 0):

First of all this code will not compile as there is an `s` present in your code.
`t.add(4);s`. Remove `s`. After removing `s` your code output will be `1 2 2 4`. And **loop** is not a `keyword` but it is `label expression` in Java

Answer (score 0):

Its a `label` Syntax

```
label strLabel:
//Labeled block of statements
```

It is possible to specify labels with `break` and `continue`

Answer (score 0):

Mate,

loop is not any keyword in java. Its a label.
Label are always used with break and continue to transfer the control flow.

Comment: There is no goto mechanism in Java. Only break and continue.